# How to send image file along with other parameter in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to send image files to SQL Server using C#.

The below code is working and saving files and their paths into the database. I need the same data in my API endpoint's response. I've created a custom response class, called `RegistrationResponse`.

I'm beginner in this so I'm looking for help.

```
public async Task<RegistrationResponse> PostFormData(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    object data = "";
    NameValueCollection col = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;

    // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);


    // Read the form data and return an async task.
    var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
        ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
            {
                Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, t.Exception);
            }
            
            //read file data
            foreach (MultipartFileData dataItem in provider.FileData)
            {
                try
                {
                    string description = string.Empty;
                    string userId = string.Empty;
                    String fileName = string.Empty;

                     // Show all the key-value pairs.
                    foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
                    {
                        foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                        {

                            if (key.ToString().ToLower() == "userid")
                            {
                                userId = val;
                            }
                            else if (key.ToString().ToLower() == "description")
                            {
                                description = val;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    String name = dataItem.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
                    fileName = userId + Path.GetExtension(name);
                    File.Move(dataItem.LocalFileName, Path.Combine(root, fileName));

                    using (var db = new AlumniDBEntities())
                    {
                            //saving path and data in database table
                        Post userPost = new Post();
                        userPost.Files = fileName;
                        userPost.Description = description;
                        userPost.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(userId);
                        userPost.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

                        db.Posts.Add(userPost);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        data = db.Posts.Where(x => x.PostID ==
                        userPost.PostID).FirstOrDefault();
                        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(ex);
                }
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        });

    var response = new RegistrationResponse
    {
        success = true,
        status = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        message = "Success",
        data = data
    };
    return response;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do?